# Vue router not working with single file components with MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to get Vue working in MeteorJS with typescript and single file components.  Sadly, it's not working.  I believe it has something to do with App.vue not having a $route property set.  Here's my `startup.ts` file. It creates a div and mounts the main app:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import App from "../imports/App.vue"

//create div to mount app
var appDiv = document.createElement("div")
appDiv.id = "app"
document.body.appendChild(appDiv)

//mount app
var AppVue = Vue.extend(App)
var mainApp = new AppVue();
mainApp.$mount("#app")
```

App.vue is dead simple:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view class="view"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import router from "./startup/router";
import LoginPage from "./client/users/pages/LoginPage/LoginPage.vue"

export default new Vue({
    router: new VueRouter({
        routes: [{
            name: "Login",
            path: "/login",
            component: new Vue({
                render: function (createElement) {
                    return createElement("p", "Login")
                }
            })
        }]
    })
})
</script>
```

MeteorJS uses commonJS, so I had to use `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` to get it working. I don't know if this causes problems. Here is my tsconfig.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

It gives me this error: 
`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"`

Looking through the code shows me that it runs into this error when attempting to render the .  The specific code attempts to get `parent.$route`, where parent is the App component.  However, for some reason App doesn't have any `$route` property!  If anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the problem was in my tsconfig. `esModuleInterop` should be true, but `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` should be false.

Next, mounting the component directly doesn't work - should have realized that. This worked:

```
var myApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(App),
    router: new VueRouter({
        routes: routes
    })
})
```

The thing is I still have the `<router-view>` in the App component.  I just moved the actual router to the parent Vue instance.